can add of interaction term makes a third term insignificant?
I was reading a paper. There are 3 regression:

the baseline regression: financial development of city i on city level deposit amount, control for road density, and the coefficient on road density is significant
add population density, and the coefficient on road density is still significant
add the interaction between population density and financial development, then coefficient on road density is no longer significant

I dont understand why adding population density and financial development separately or interactively would change the significance of the third variable: road density
Can someone explains to me what might be the reason? or it is wrong?
Thank you!

https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=regression+coefficient+change+not+significant++

There is no reason this can't happen.  Unless the variables are orthogonal (and yours are not) then we expect changes in parameter estimates when we add nee variables, whether main effects or interactions.
Also, the change from "significant" to "not significant" is not particularly interesting. Look at changes in effect size. If the effect size for road density goes down when you add the interaction, then it means that some of he relationship between density and financial development is captured by that interaction.
As to substantive reasons why this might happen -- I don't know.  But a subject matter expert may be able to say.

Hi Peter, thx for the reply. But I don't get how can the road density not capture the effect when PD and financial development are added separatly but now there is something new when I add interaction. Clearly it can be different if I move from a model without PD to with PD, but from adding separately to adding interaction, and it is not the coeffcient of the interaction variables but a third control variable, I do not understand. Some simple example clarify what are the additional effect being capture that would affect this third variable will be appreciated.

The additional effect is that of the interaction. I might be able to make up an example, but you already have one.
